# String losing data when assigning to TStringList

Tags: delphi, string, unicode, delphi-2009, char

I have this method,

```
var
s : TStringList;
fVar : string;
begin
s := TStringList.Create;
fVar := ZCompressStr('text');

ShowMessage( IntToStr(length(fVar) * SizeOf(Char)) );
//24

s.text := fVar;  

ShowMessage( IntToStr( length(s.text) * SizeOf(Char)) );
//18
end;
```

The ZCompressStr is from http://www.base2ti.com/zlib.htm with Line 121 changed from
{$ifndef UNICODE}
to
{$ifdef UNICODE}
to make it compile.

Anyway, I can call ZDecompressStr if I use the fVar variable, however once I move it to a stringlist or to a memo it seems to loose those 6 bytes of data.... If I try and use ZDecompressStr on the s.text var it fails with buffer error.

Comment: Why are you using a TStringList?

Comment: If you provide a description of what you are trying to accomplish, you will be more likely to get answers that help you accomplish your goal.  For example, tstringlist may not be the best tool (an array of strings might be better, for example) and certainly assigning to tstringlist.text may be causing some of your confusion (the tstringlist.add method might be what you want).  It's hard to tell, though, from your question.

Comment: The reason I am using a TStringList is because I want to save the data to file once I have compressed it - and for that I have generally always used TStringList. It appears this is a no no which I have been getting away with however with D2009 it has caught me out.

Answer (score 14):

There is no reason you should have had to change line 121 of *ZLibEx.pas*; it is correct for all versions of Delphi, including Delphi 2009. The `UNICODE` symbol should *only* be defined for Delphi 2009, and when it is, the type definitions for `RawByteString`, `UnicodeString`, and `UnicodeChar` should all be skipped because they're already intrinsic types in the language.

`ZCompressStr` will generate a string that may contain non-printable characters, including null bytes. It stores its result in a `RawByteString`, which Delphi treats specially.

`TStringList`, like just about everything else in Delphi 2009, uses Unicode. Its `Text` property is of type `UnicodeString`. When you assign *any* non-`UnicodeString` value to `UnicodeString`, you get a conversion, as from the [`MultiByteToWideStr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072.aspx) API function. Even `RawByteString` is included in that rule. If you haven't assigned a code-page-specific string value to a `RawByteString`, then it will have code page 0, which is `CP_ACP`, the default code page for your system.

If the string doesn't really contain characters encoded according to the system code page, then any conversion is asking for trouble: garbage in, garbage out. In particular, there's no guarantee that you'll get the same number of characters.

[As Smok1 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351302/string-losing-data-when-assigning-to-tstringlist/1351383#1351383), `TStringList.Text` is a property. It has a setter method that splits the given string into separate lines. When you read the property, it re-joins all those lines into a single string again. While *setting* the property, `TStrings.SetTextStr` (in *Classes.pas*, if you're curious) will split the line at any occurrence of `#0`, `#10`, or `#13`. That is, null characters, line feeds, and carriage returns. When re-joining all the lines, it will use its `LineBreak` property, which is initialized with the global `sLineBreak` variable. A line break is also put after the last string, so every line ends with `LineBreak`. Therefore, the conversion won't necessarily round-trip.

So, there are two things to learn from this:

1. Don't treat compressed data as text.
2. Don't use `TStrings` descendants to hold things that you don't want to treat a multiple strings.

Another good piece of advice: Don't use `string` as a generic data-storage type. Only use it for actual text. For storage of arbitrary binary data, prefer `TBytes`, or a `TMemoryStream`. Using your example, you could compress a string like this:

```
var
  ss: TStream;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  ss := TStringStream.Create('text');
  try
    ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(ss.Size));
      ZCompressStream(ss, ms);
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(ms.Size));
    finally
      ms.Free;
    end;
  finally
    ss.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Good point. In fact TStringList is quit clever so no matter if DOS-style or unix-style end-of-line is being used.

Comment: Thanks Rob this is a fantastic answer. Your first paragraph - yes it is strange but have you downloaded and tried to use that ZlibEx for their website it simply wouldn't compile until I changed that line, see also https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=130234

The reset of the answer is absolutely spot on. I have been using TStrlingList because I want to savetofile (which TMemoryStream can do) but I am going to want to POST this data via a form over the internet. I will write this bit up and modify my question a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This may be the conversion - TStringList.Text property is a property, not variable. You are using it in a bit dangerous way, since there is some processing of Text inside TStringList.

Comment: I have been downwoted. It would be nice to know what was actually wrong with my answer?